# html5 database wont display data in div from append

Tags: database, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

Below is the code of the internal database table from which I want to display the result in a div

```
var sear=$("#search").val();
var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO", [],
 function (tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length, i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      $('#output2').append('<tr>td>'+ results.rows.item(i).D_Indications +'</td></tr>');
    alert(results.rows.item(i).D_Indications);
  }
});


    });
```

I can view the result in alert but I cant view it in the div

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. table-tag is missing
2. Typo in call to append(...). Look at opening tags tr td.